# How to get list from another form for download with webclient?

Tags: c#, list

How to get list from another form and download files on the that list via web client one by one.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm going to assume that the other list is a collection of URL endpoints which contain file content. Knowing this, we could do something like:

```
var urls = MyFormName.ItemsSource
```

Or

```
var urls = MyFormName.ItemsSource.Cast<Type>();
```

Knowing this, we now can donwload the data from each URL:

```
using System.Net

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
foreach(var endpoint in urls){
webClient.DownloadFile(endpoint, myFileLocation);
}
```

From there, you can grab all the urls and download their content into a folder. If you want to read the downloaded file contents to a byte array or so, you could re read the file using

```
using(var file = File.OpenRead(filePAth)){}
```

If you want, you can also download tyo a byte array using:

```
byte[] response = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(endpoint);
```

Comment: What stops you from parsing the xml data in the second form? Why does it need to go through form 1?

Comment: List created on Form1(Taking url addresses from xml), but i want to call the list to Form2 and download them on that form. Also its trying to download multiple file at one time. I want to download one by one.

Comment: on form1 there is file integrity check if any of files re corrupted adding them to list after that its check for updates for files again and its adding the files which re out of date.